# Capturing the same variable in one of multiple closures

Tags: closures, rust

I have two closures that capture the same `Vec` and I don't know how to write this in idiomatic Rust:

```
use std::error;

fn get_token -> Box<Vec<u8>>() {...}
fn do_stuff(file: &str) -> std::io::Result<i32> {...}
fn do_other_stuff(a: &str, a: &str) -> std::io::Result<i32> {...}

enum MyError {
    IoError { token: Vec<u8>, reason: String ),
}

fn consumer() -> Result<MyError, ()> {
    let token = get_token();

    try!(do_stuff("a")
        .map_err(|e| MyError::IoError { token: token, reason: "foo".to_str() }));
    try!(do_other_stuff("b", "c")
        .map_err(|e| MyError::IoError { token: token, reason: "bar".to_str() }));
}
```

I could replace the `map_err` calls with `match` expressions but I really am stumped by this: how do I pass a `Vec` to multiple closures?

Comment: may i ask, why is the output of `get_token`, `Box<Vec<u8>>` rather than just `Vec<u8>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Please make sure to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the future, it's not fun to have to fix syntax errors before being able to reproduce your problem: http://is.gd/tXr7WK

Rust does not know that the only way the second closure can run, is if the first closure did not run and will never run. You can either wait for the [`let/else`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1303) RFC to be accepted, implemented and stabilized, or you can create your error in steps, first create an inner closure that does all the operations for that one error kind without using up the `token`, then run the closure, then map the error to your custom error type.

```
|| -> _ {
    try!(do_stuff("a").map_err(|e| ("foo".to_owned(), e)));
    try!(do_other_stuff("b","c").map_err(|e| ("bar".to_owned(), e)));
    Ok(())
} ().map_err(|(reason, e)| MyError::IoError{ token: token, reason: reason })
```

There's something weird going on where the closure requires us to specify that it returns something with `-> _`, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the playground next time I post something. Apologies.

Comment: Nice solution... but oh is this `|| -> _ { ...  } ()` pattern perl like!

Answer (score 3):

Much more straightforward is to just not use `try!` or closures:

```
if let Err(e) = do_stuff("a") {
    return Err(MyError::IoError{token: token, reason: "foo".to_owned()});
}
if let Err(e) = do_other_stuff("b", "c") {
    return Err(MyError::IoError{token: token, reason: "bar".to_owned()});
}
```

This lets Rust perform straightforward analysis like you want it to, and is much more readable than dancing through hoops.

Comment: the problem with this is that you loose the `Ok` value, but since that's not required in this question anyway, your answer is the prettiest.

Comment: @ker You can `match` instead if you want the `Ok` value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `and_then()` combinator to avoid additional closure:

```
try!(do_stuff("a").map_err(|_| "foo" )
        .and_then(|_|
            do_other_stuff("b","c").map_err(|_| "bar")
        )
        .map_err(|e| MyError::IoError{token:token,reason:e.into()})
);
```